# Equi-continuous family and bounded sup-norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f \in C([0, 1])$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $||f||_{\infty} \leq 1$. Prove that the sequence of powers $f, f^2, f^3,\ldots$ is equi-continuous if and only if $||f||_{\infty} < 1$.

I proved if $||f||_{\infty} < 1$ then $f, f^2, f^3,\ldots$ is equi-continuous. How can I prove another direction? Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$.  Note that $1-x^n < \epsilon$ when $\sqrt[n]{1-\epsilon}\leq x$...

Comment: Hmmm... Could you say more? (Why should one consider a specific $f$ when the question is about quite general $f$? Could you say more?)

Comment: @WlodAA  Sure, although the idea is the same as the above example.  Let $a:= \inf f^{-1} (1)$.  Note that $f(a)=1$ by continuity, and since $f(0)=0$, we have $0 < a$.  By the intermediate value theorem, we may chose $b \in (0,a)$ with $0 < f(b) < 1$.  Now repeat the argument that's in the example to show $\{f^n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is not equicontinuous at $a$.